# how to convert Week/Year (10/2018) to date format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, week-number

I have pandas dataframe in the format 10/2018, 10 represents the week of the year and 2018 the year. How do I convert them to complete date which will be march 5th 2018

week/year             Date
10/2018               05-03-2018

I have pandas dataframe in the format 10/2018, 10 represents the week of the year and 2018 the year. How do I convert them to complete date which will be march 5th 2018

Please help me for the same. i have tried multiple option but nothing seems to working

`week/year             Date`

`10/2018               05-03-2018`

```
tried this:df_2018_to_2022['TimeDesc'] = pd.to_datetime((df_2018_to_2022['week']-1).astype(str) + "6", format="%Y%U%w")
```

error:

```
OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1020-04-29 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proposition with [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) :

```
out = (
        df
          .join(df["week/year"].str.split("/", expand=True))
          .assign(date= lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x.pop(1).astype(str) + x.pop(0).astype(str) + "1",
                                                 format='%G%V%w').dt.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))
      )
​
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)

  week/year        date
0   10/2018  05-03-2018
```

*DataFrame used :*

```
print(df)

  week/year
0   10/2018
```